# Permitted Sub-queries in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in the Snowflake documentation it lists the types of sub-query that are supported [Types Supported by Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#types-supported-by-snowflake):

- Uncorrelated scalar subqueries in any place that a value expression can be used.
- Correlated scalar subqueries in WHERE clauses.
- EXISTS, ANY / ALL, and IN subqueries in WHERE clauses. These
  subqueries can be correlated or uncorrelated.

However, in the documentation about [windows functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/functions-window-using.html#windowing-concepts) (as an example) it gives this SQL which runs without error:

```
select branch_id,
       net_profit as store_profit,
       (select sum(net_profit) from store_sales as s2 where s2.city = s1.city) as city_profit,
       store_profit / city_profit * 100 as store_percentage_of_city_profit
    from store_sales as s1
    order by branch_id;
```

From my understanding:

- city_profit is defined by a sub-query and that sub-query is correlated (it is referencing S1)
- It is not covered by any of the 3 rules regarding allowable sub-queries (it is not uncorrelated, it is not in a WHERE clause and it is not "EXISTS, ANY / ALL, and IN subqueries in WHERE clauses"

Therefore the query should be invalid but as it isn't I am obviously missing something. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can simply manually transform your SQL query to use [`LATERAL`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral) instead:

```sql
SELECT
  branch_id
  net_profit AS store_profit
  city_profit,
  store_profit / city_profit * 100 AS store_percentage_of_city_profit
FROM store_sales AS s1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT sum(net_profit)
  FROM store_sales AS s2
  WHERE s2.city = s1.city
) AS t (city_profit)
ORDER BY branch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query in the question falls in the first point. Correlated Subquery in a WHERE clause. Correlated means, the subquery and main query should be joined in a where clause.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).